# How convert array with integer and nill to string?

Tags: go

Let's say I have array with `integer` and `nil` elements:

```
[15698, nil, 13000, 560365, nil]
```

I want to convert this array to string where each element separated by `,`.

```
[15698, null, 13000, 560365, null]
```

I tried next code but it return 0 instead of null. How to fix it?

```
func ConvertIntArrayToString(input []int) string {
    if len(input) == 0 {
        return ""
    }
    estimate := len(input) * 4
    b := make([]byte, 0, estimate)
    for _, n := range input {
        b = strconv.AppendInt(b, int64(n), 10)
        b = append(b, ',')
    }
    b = b[:len(b)-1]
    return string(b)
}
```

---

Here is how I created array:

```
type NilInt struct {
    value int
    null  bool
}

func (n *NilInt) Value() interface{} {
    if n.null {
        return nil
    }
    return n.value
}

func NewInt(x int) NilInt {
    return NilInt{x, false}
}

func NewNil() NilInt {
    return NilInt{0, true}
}

var x = []utils.NilInt{utils.NewNil(), utils.NewInt(10), utils.NewNil(), utils.NewInt(5)}]

var result strings.Builder

for _, n := range x {
    if n.Value() == nil {
        result.WriteString("null,")
    } else {
        result.WriteString(??? + ",")
    }
}

fmt.Println(result)
```

Comment: "Let's say I have array with integer and nil elements" - nope, you don't. This array/slice is impossible in go (if type is `[]int`)

Comment: Neither an `int` nor a `string` can be `nil`. What is the exact input, and what output are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I understand that Go is a strongly typed programming language. In my case, such a dynamic array comes in the body of the POST request. As I understand I need to create such array firstly and then manipulate him.

Comment: Then you need to show more code, because the `[]int` the quoted function accepts literally cannot contain any `nil` values.

Comment: The string value `null` is commonly used in json. Are you trying to encode something as json?

Comment: If your slice needs to accept values of a non-nilable type and `nil`s as well you can use a slice of interfaces: https://play.golang.com/p/hEjTFIoJlXj or change the type to a pointer type to make it nillable: https://play.golang.com/p/Hv8I4yU71ji

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek where you have `???` you can use `strconv.Itoa(n.Value().(int))`

Comment: @mkopriva thank you for your answer! Can you post your first link code with some explanation if you want, not comment. I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @mkopriva thank you for your previous comment. My version is working `strconv.Itoa(n.Value().(int))`, but not elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by others, an int slice (`[]int`) cannot contain `nil` values because it is illegal to assign `nil` to a variable of a type whose specified [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) is not `nil`.

If you need a slice that can hold `int` values and `nil`s you can use  `[]interface{}`. Then, to construct the desired string you can simply marshal such a slice with the `encoding/json` package.

```
var a = []interface{}{15698, nil, 13000, 560365, nil}
b, err := json.Marshal(a)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

https://play.golang.com/p/hEjTFIoJlXj